# Composer autoload not including my custom namespaces (Silex)

Tags: php, composer-php, silex, autoload

I'm developing a REST API with Silex and I'm facing a problem regarding autoloading of my custom librairy. It looks like Composer's autoload is not including it, because when I include it myself it works.

```
# The autoload section in composer.json
# Tried with :
#    "Oc\\": "src/Oc"
#    "Oc\\": "src/"
#    "": "src/"

"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Oc\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php
// api/index.php <-- public-facing API

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require __DIR__.'/../src/app.php';

require __DIR__.'/../src/routes.php'; // <--

$app->run();
```

---

```
<?php
// src/routes.php

// When uncommented, it works!
//include('Oc/ParseImport.php');

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Oc\ParseImport;

$app->get('/hello', function () use ($app) {
  return new Response(Oc\ParseImport(), 200);
});
```

---

```
<?php
// src/Oc/ParseImport.php

namespace Oc {
  function ParseImport() {
    return 'foobar!';
  }
}
```

I run `composer dumpautoload` after each `composer.json` manipulation, and I do see the line `'Oc\\' => array($baseDir . '/src/Oc')` (or anything I tried) in `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`.

I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: What is the exact issue i think you have overweighted your question with extra stuffs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost everything you did was correct.

When trying to autoload classes in a namespace, given that a class is named `Oc\Foo` and is located in the file `src/Oc/Foo.php`, the correct autoloading would be `"PSR-4": { "Oc\\": "src/Oc" }`.

However, you do not have a class. You have a function. And functions cannot be autoloaded by PHP until now. It has been proposed more than once (the one proposal I found easily is https://wiki.php.net/rfc/function_autoloading), but until now this feature hasn't been implemented.

Your alternative solutions:

1. Move the function into a static method of a class. Classes can be autoloaded.
2. Include the function definition as "files" autoloading: `"files": ["src/Oc/ParseImport.php"]` Note that this approach will always include that file even if it isn't being used - but there is no other way to include functions in PHP.

As illustration see how Guzzle did it:
[Autoloading in composer.json](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/6.2.3/composer.json#L26)
[Conditional include of functions](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/6.2.3/src/functions_include.php) based on `function_exists`
[Function definition](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/6.2.3/src/functions.php)